# Meteor Client calling findOne in Server Method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a client-side form that can create a document upon submission. I want to see if one of the input fields already exists on a Document in the DB though. This would then alert the user and ask them if they want to continue creating the record.

Client-side event

```
Template.createDoc.events({
    'click button[type=submit]'(e, template) {

        //This particular example is checking to see if a Doc with its `name` property set to `value` already exists

        const value = $('#name');
        const fieldName = 'name';

        const exists = Meteor.call('checkIfFieldExistsOnDoc', fieldName, value);
        if (exists) {
            if (confirm(`Doc with ${value} as its ${fieldName} already exists. Are you sure you want to continue creating Doc?`) {
               //db.Docs.insert....
           }
        }
    }
});
```

Server-side Meteor Method

```
'checkIfFieldExistsOnDoc'(field, val) {
    
    if (this.isServer) {
      this.unblock();
      check(field, String);
      check(val, String);

      if (!this.userId) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized', 'You are not authorized.');
      }

      const findObj = {};
      findObj[field] = val;

      const fieldsObj = {};
      fieldsObj[fieldsObj] = 1;

      const doc = Docs.findOne(findObj, {fields: fieldsObj});
      return doc;
    }
  },
```

My issue is that the client-side code always gets undefined back when calling the Server method. I now understand why, however, I'm not keen on wrapping all of my subsequent client-code into a callback yet.

So - any other ideas on how I can attempt to do this simple feature?

Also - I was thinking of having the client-side page's `onCreated` do a 1-time server call to get ALL `names` for all `Docs`, storing this in memory, and then doing the check upon form submission using this. Obviously, this is inefficient and not-scalable, although it would work

Answer (score 3):

Meteor.call in the client side is always an async call. Then you need implement a callback.

See docs: https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-call

```
Meteor.call('checkIfFieldExistsOnDoc', fieldName, value, function(error, result) {
  if (result) {
    if (confirm(`Doc with ${value} as its ${fieldName} already exists. Are you sure you want to continue creating Doc?`) {
      //db.Docs.insert....
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was some way to avoid the `cb` syntax though. I know removing the param on server adds some syntactical sugar to make it 'synchronous' kinda like `await`.. So - just wondering if there was way to do that on client-side too

Comment: @user2402616, try async/await, but remember that you will lost a big advantage to frontend that have some async calls to render your page.

Answer (score 2):

On the client, you can wrap any Meteor.call with a Promise and then use it with async/await. There are some packages on Atmosphere that do this for you to.

I've used this package for years: https://atmospherejs.com/deanius/promise

On the client I often just use `await Meteor.callPromise()` which returns a response nicely.

Here are a couple of the best write-ups on the many options available to you:

1. https://blog.meteor.com/using-promises-on-the-client-in-meteor-fb4f1c155f84
2. https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-methods-return-values-via-promise-async/42060
3. https://dev.to/jankapunkt/async-meteor-method-calls-24f9

Comment: Is it considered "bad" practice to have patterns like this where client-code calls async to server? I would think not haha as that is one of the benefits of JS. I'm questioning it only because I'm realizing this is really the first time I've had to do it in Meteor

Comment: Many features of Meteor were originally designed before async/await was added to JS, so that is why it used to be less common to make async/await calls from the client, but now it is very common in Meteor community.   One of the best things about Meteor is the open DDP connection between client & server, so async/await calls are very fast over that open connection.